# HttpWebRequest runs slowly first time within SQLCLR

Tags: sql-server-2005, sqlclr

When making an HttpWebRequest within a CLR stored procedure (as per the code below), the first invocation after the Sql Server is (re-)started or after a given (but indeterminate) period of time waits for quite a length of time on the GetResponse() method call.

Is there any way to resolve this that doesn't involve a "hack" such as having a Sql Server Agent job running every few minutes to try and ensure that the first "slow" call is made by the Agent and not "real" production code?

```
function SqlString MakeWebRequest(string address, string parameters, int connectTO)
{
  SqlString returnData;
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Concat(address.ToString(), "?", parameters.ToString())); 
  request.Timeout = (int)connectTO;
  request.Method = "GET";
  using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
  {
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
      {
        SqlString responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        returnData = responseFromServer;
      }
    }
  }
  response.Close();

  return returnData;
}
```

(Error handling and other non-critical code has ben removed for brevity)

---

See also [this Sql Server forums thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlnetfx/thread/06545328-cb24-45bd-835c-db93f13bbe95/?prof=required).

Comment: How long is this first call wait time vs 2nd+ call times?  Is this call to the same URI usually?

Comment: I believe (off the top of my head) it' 30 seconds, and the call is made to a URL that is an IP address, so I don't think DNS would be an issue :(

Comment: Did you consider looking at the HTTP traffic with something like WireShark? Or has everything on the wire been ruled out.

Comment: I wasn't able to capture any web traffic for my CLR code with Fiddler.

Comment: @KennyEvitt, Fiddler != Wireshark. Wireshark uses WinPcap to access network traffic at the system level (i.e. ALL traffic on the system). Fiddler shows HTTP/HTTPS traffic for the logged in users session. Your CLR is inside SQL Server which is running as a different user AND in a different session.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a problem for me using `HttpWebRequest` at first. It's due to the the class looking for a proxy to use. If you set the object's `Proxy` value to `null`/`Nothing`, it'll zip right along.

Comment: This definitely seems to have been the cause of the *bulk of* the (much) longer duration of the initial call. But there's still (maybe) a small difference remaining. Any ideas on what else might be making the initial calls slower (when using `HttpWebRequest`)?

Answer (score 4):

Looks to me like code signing verification. The MS shipped system dlls are all signed and SQL verifies the signatures at load time. Apparently the certificate revocation list is expired and the certificate verification engine times out retrieving a new list. I have blogged about this problem before [Fix slow application startup due to code sign validation](http://rusanu.com/2009/07/24/fix-slow-application-startup-due-to-code-sign-validation/) and the problem is also described in this Technet article: [Certificate Revocation and Status Checking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457027.aspx).

The solution is pretty arcane and involves registry editing of the key: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CertDllCreateCertificateChainEngine\Config`:

- **ChainUrlRetrievalTimeoutMilliseconds** This is each individual CRL check call timeout. If is 0 or not present the default value of 15 seconds is used. Change this timeout to a reasonable value like 200 milliseconds.
- **ChainRevAccumulativeUrlRetrievalTimeoutMilliseconds** This is the aggregate CRL retrieval timeout. If set to 0 or not present the default value of 20 seconds is used. Change this timeout to a value like 500 milliseconds.

There is also a more specific solution for [Microsoft signed assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc615012%28BTS.10%29.aspx) (this is from the Biztalk documentation, but applies to any assembly load):

> **Manually load Microsoft Certificate
>   Revocation lists**
>
> When starting a .NET application, the
>   .NET Framework will attempt to
>   download the Certificate Revocation
>   list (CRL) for any signed assembly. If
>   your system does not have direct
>   access to the Internet, or is
>   restricted from accessing the
>   Microsoft.com domain, this may delay
>   startup of BizTalk Server. To avoid
>   this delay at application startup, you
>   can use the following steps to
>   manually download and install the code
>   signing Certificate Revocation Lists
>   on your system.
>
> 1. Download the latest CRL updates from
>      http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/CodeSignPCA.crl
>      and
>      http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/CodeSignPCA2.crl.
> 2. Move the CodeSignPCA.crl and CodeSignPCA2.crl files to the isolated
>      system.
> 3. From a command prompt, enter the following command to use the certutil
>      utility to update the local
>      certificate store with the CRL
>      downloaded in step 1:
>        certutil –addstore CA c:\CodeSignPCA.crl
>
> The CRL files are updated regularly,
>   so you should consider setting a
>   reoccurring task of downloading and
>   installing the CRL updates. To view
>   the next update time, double-click the
>   .crl file and view the value of the
>   Next Update field.

Comment: Of course is a bit unusual that server making web service calls cannot acceess the CRL server so I may waay off, but the symptoms look much like CRL check.

Comment: That is very useful to know. I have hit the CRL timeout issue in another form (.NET C# code loading TIFF images makes a CRL request that times-out because the PCs are not internet-connected, causing image load to take 30 secs). The Registry hack is a bit dodgy, but loading the CRL manually seems to be a sensible solution.

Comment: @Craig: Yes, basically any appdomain creation can hit this, and is almost impossible to diagnose unless you know about it. First hit on a ASP web site, first call into a dll, app freezes for 30 seconds at load, all symptoms of the same issue.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Switching to the proxy addressed this issue, but this explains why. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but if the delay long enough that initial DNS lookups could be the culprit? 
( how long is the delay verse a normal call? )

and/or

Is this URI internal to the Network / or a different internal network?

I have seen some weird networking delays from using load balance profiles inside a network that isn't setup right, the firewalls, load-balancers, and other network profiles might be "fighting" the initial connections...

I am not a great networking guy, but you might want to see what an SA has to say about this on serverfault.com as well...

good luck

Answer (score 0):

There is always a delay the first time SQLCLR loads the necessary assemblies.
That should be the case not only for your function MakeWebRequest, but also for any .NET function in the SQLCLR.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the issue here, or doesn't appear to be, as any other function in our CLR Assembly can be called and executed, but the first time this one is called it blocks on "request.GetResponse()"

Answer (score 0):

HttpWebRequest is part of the System.Net assembly, which is not part of the [supported libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx).
I'd recommend using the library System.Web.Services instead to make web service calls from inside the SQLCLR.

Comment: Again, not the issue. We're using other parts of System.Net without any issue whatsoever. "Supported" or otherwise is irrelevant in the context of this question. Plus, System.Web.Services is for *creating* web services, not loading web pages / calling web services..

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and my first cold run (after SQL service restart) was in 3 seconds (not 30 as yours), all others are in 0 sec.

The code sample I've used to build a DLL:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace MySQLCLR
{
    public static class WebRequests
    {
        public static void MakeWebRequest(string address, string parameters, int connectTO)
        {
            string returnData;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Concat(address.ToString(), "?", parameters.ToString()));
            request.Timeout = (int)connectTO;
            request.Method = "GET";
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        returnData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                    responseStream.Close();
                }
                response.Close();
            }
            SqlDataRecord rec = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData[] { new SqlMetaData("response", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10000000) });
            rec.SetValue(0, returnData);
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(rec);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just confirmed with my colleague that the delay is circa 15 seconds, not the 30 that I thought it was and this occurs after Sql Server restart or a certain inactivity period that we've yet to identify (i.e. overnight)

Comment: So the problem lays somewhere else, we just don't have an environment to reproduce it. Do you think 3s for cold start is unacceptable?