# Winform application first web request is slow

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, httpwebrequest

When I first make a HttpWebRequest in a Winform App, it takes 10~30 seconds to process the first request. Subsequent calls takes less than a second. I wrote a little POC app to exemplify this, it consists of two buttons and 2 textBoxes, an image of the app can be found here (I can't upload images here yet...):

[image]

The app code is very simple:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DateTime _start;
    TimeSpan _span;
    int _count = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _count++;
        _start = DateTime.Now;
        HttpWebRequest _request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text); ;
        // Added after Conrad's response:
        _request.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
        HttpWebResponse _response = (HttpWebResponse)_request.GetResponse(); 
        _response.Close();
        _span = DateTime.Now - _start;
        textBox2.Text += _count.ToString("000") + ": " + _span.ToString(@"mm\:ss\,fff") + "\r\n";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Why does it take so long in the 1st request? There is something I can do to speed this up?

Comment: Are you testing against a public site or some sort of local resource?  How does the speed compare to just loading in the browser?  Are you sure the hit isn't because the remote server is having to spin up some resource that has been idle?

Comment: Jason, the URL I'm using is public (http://www.maxprocess.com.br/status.htm), it's a quick & dirty html page in our company site, with only 33 bytes (<html><body>Ok</body></html>). When I access this page via browser (IE or FF), it loads instantaneously, as expected. The lag is only in my WinForm app.

Comment: I'd suggest running it through a profiler to see if you can get any insight into what all is happening under the covers.

Comment: Try running with Fiddler2.  That should tell you if the delay is between the application and the website, or someplace within the application.  It will also let you see if you application is sending things differently than a browser would (different headers, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the proxy property to null it will work as well, even without disabling the logical cards.

Source: [HttpWebRequest runs slowly first time within SQLCLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292637/httpwebrequest-runs-slowly-first-time-within-sqlclr)

Answer (score 2):

Mystery solved, thank you all guys for the insigths. Using Fiddler2 (Many thanks, [Bradley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526724/bradley-uffner) & [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason)!),I was able to determine the problem was on my notebook. I have one MS-Loopback & one VirtualBox adapter, that I use for tests with PDA's & VM's. When one or both are enabled, the app took too long to determine the gateway for the connection. When I disabled both logical cards, the lag was gone.

I still think there is something weird with the WinForm app/.Net, because my browsers (IE/FF) does not suffer from this problem. Maybe there is a way to tweak the .NET or my app to ignore this adapters, but since I'm a almost complete webnorant (Web-ignorant), I'm happy to have find this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are few different firsts but basically there's a fair bit of set up to do for your first hit. You could twiddle around the edges but the value you'd get from the effort is dubious. It certainly isn't going to be 29 seconds...

The "quick" approach is just to make a throw away request in another thread as near the first thing your app does as possible.

Comment: Tony, it's a reasonable workaround, but I wish to know WHY a WinForm app have this behavior, since in the browsers I use (IE/FF) the URL is loaded instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an IIS setting on your web-service.  Try [auto-start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677285.aspx) to reduce first request latency.